# How to transport factor labels to another variable elegantly?

Tags: r

I've surprisingly haven't been able to find a solution. So let's say I have two variables:

```
gender1 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)
gender2 <- sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE)
gender2[gender2==1] <- 2

gender1[gender1==1] <- 3

gender1 <- factor(gender1, levels = c(0, 1, 2, 3), labels = c("Male", "Female", "Intersex", "Other"))
```

I'm looking to do to things:

1. How do I list the labels of gender1 so I know which label matches with values. So far, all the solutions I've found requires I look at ordering. But that can get complex when I have over 100 factor levels in complex surveys. In Stata, I would use -lab list *label*- For instance, I want a list that says:

   > LevelsofVar(gender1)
   > 0 "Male"
   > 1 "Female"
   > 2 "Intersex"
   > 3 "Other"
2. How do I transfer the factor labels from gender1 to gender2, such that the correct numbers match? In Stata, I would just use -lab val gender2 *label*-

Comment: Try `levels(factor1)=levels(factor2)`

Comment: doesn't work. It adds levels but doesn't label the values

Answer (score 0):

Taking `gender2` `as.factor` and assign `` `levels<-` `` as sequence `0:3` which we get from `seq` over the `levels(gender1)` minus `1` because the result starts at `1`. This inner bracket has an attribute `"levels"` that we modify via `` `attr<-` `` with `levels(gender1)`.

```
gender2 <- `attr<-`(`levels<-`(as.factor(gender2), seq(levels(gender1)) - 1),
                    "levels", levels(gender1))

stopifnot(all.equal(levels(gender1), levels(gender2)))
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
gender1 <- sample(c(0, 2), 20, replace=TRUE)
gender2 <- sample(c(0, 3), 20, replace=TRUE)

gender1 <- factor(gender1, levels=0:3, labels=c("Male", "Female", "Intersex", "Other"))
```